# Load a particular div from an href jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know how to load a complete html page into a div using jquery, but how do I load just one div from a page? Here's my script:

```
$('.open-alert,.help').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".overlay").fadeIn();
    $('.overlay').load(this.href, function() {});
    $("body").addClass("masked");
})
}
```

When a user clicks a link with the help class, I want it to load a div with a specific id.

So a link that looks like this:

```
<a class="help" href="help.htm#help-one">Help message one</a>
```

Should load just this div from help.htm:

```
<div id="help-one">Help message one</div>
```

But that doesn't seem to work. It loads the whole page. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use

```
var href= $(this).attr('href');
var splitit = href.split('#');
$('.overlay').load(splitit[0]+' #'+splitit[1]);
```

in one line

```
$('.overlay').load(($(this).attr('href').split('#'))[0]+' #'+($(this).attr('href').split('#'))[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Loading a specific div should look like this 
`.load('help.htm #help-one')`
Without a space in between, #help-one would be considered as a URL fragment.

You can do something like this as a quick fix.

```
var href = this.href.replace('#', ' #'); // <--- replace '#' with ' #'
$('.overlay').load(href, function() {

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would alter your code slightly...

```
$('.open-alert,.help').click(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        target = $this.attr('data-target'),

    $(".overlay").fadeIn();
    $('.overlay').load(target);
    $("body").addClass("masked");
});
```

and the html:

```
<a class="help" data-target="help.htm #help-one" href="javascript:void(0);">Help message one</a>
```

Notice the space in the `data-target`... It's important. Also, doing it this way makes it clearer what your code is up to when the link is clicked.